# MySQL: WHERE status NOT LIKE 'example%' isn't returning results with NULL status

Tags: mysql, null, sql-like

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
+---------+----------+-----------------+
| name    |   age    | status          |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
| Clark   |   25     | Example         |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
| Peter   |   28     | Example2        |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
| Waldo   |   37     | NULL            |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
| Tarzan  |   31     | Unknown         |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
```

When I perform a query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE status NOT LIKE 'example%'
```

I get:

```
+---------+----------+-----------------+
| name    |   age    | status          |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
| Tarzan  |   31     | Unknown         |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
```

If I change the query to (notice that **I removed the `NOT`**):

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE status LIKE 'example%'
```

I then get the following:

```
+---------+----------+-----------------+
| name    |   age    | status          |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
| Clark   |   25     | Example         |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
| Peter   |   28     | Example2        |
+---------+----------+-----------------+
```

My question is: **where's Waldo?**

Comment: Upvoted because I had this same question, and the "Where's Waldo?" reference actually made this both entertaining and educational. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, `NULL` values cannot participate in most comparison operations, including `LIKE`, instead you must consider `NULL` values separately using the `IS NULL` operator:

```
WHERE (`status` NOT LIKE '%example%' OR `status` IS NULL)
```

It's silly, but that's life.

This is documented here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/working-with-null.html

> You cannot use [...] comparison operators such as =, <, or <> to test for NULL. Because the result of any [...] comparison with NULL is also NULL, you cannot obtain any meaningful results from such comparisons.

Comment: Ahh, thanks @Dai, I actually knew the answer already and was just trying to put it on StackOverflow for anyone else who might have the problem but thank you for the correct answer anyway!  The document you linked though talks about comparison operators, but not the `LIKE` one, which I *thought* was a different construct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure *why* MySQL doesn't like handling `LIKE` on `NULL` values, but the solution that worked for me was changing the query to the following:

```
SELECT * FROM records WHERE (status IS NULL OR status NOT LIKE 'example%')
```

I cannot find any documentation about this issue, so if anyone has some good stuff please share, but at least this works.

Comment: This behavior is entirely by design should not surprise anyone.   `NULL` is a placeholder for the absence of a value, and a value that is absent cannot properly be said to be *either* like, or not like, any other value.  Is the expression `1 > NULL` true, or false?  The answer is "neither."  The average of (2,0,4) is obviously 2, but the average of (2,NULL,4) is 3.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in `three valued logic`. `WHERE` clause will only filter rows where predicate **evaluates to TRUE**. It will filter out rows where predicate evaluates to `FALSE` or `NULL`. Since `null like something` is `NULL` it will not be in result.